# connect to gitlab project using ssh key

Tags: macos, gitlab, ssh-keys

Please i added an ssh key on gitlab (public_rsa).

My problem is that I am still asked for my gitlab password and passphrase when i tried to push a branch on repository. My understanding was that after I set up this SSH key, I would no longer have to do that.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "gregory@gmail.com" -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa_specific
```

If someone can help to give an explanation i would appreciate it.
Tell me if im not clear .

Thank you.

Comment: Because you are not using the default ssh key file name. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths

Answer (score 0):

I see you listed the command that generates the rsa key. You didn't mention if you placed that key in Gitlab or where.

I would first double check that you have copied and pasted the contents of `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa_specific` into your Gitlab accounts settings >> ssh keys.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account

Then I would try checking the ssh key by running the following command in a terminal:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#testing-that-everything-is-set-up-correctly

Comment: thank you for your response,  yes i paste it in settings>> ssh keys.

Comment: when i type the command, im asking to enter the passphrase.